# How can i add the functionality in my web App So that my Application user can create their Paypal Account using API in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, paypal-sandbox

Actually in my application i want the functionality in which user can create their paypal's account on API calling or any SDk function invoking I want this implementation in node js I integrated the package

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-adaptive

because it has a function of

```
paypalSdk.createAccount(payload, callback);
```

but error occurs besides this i dont know is it a perfect approach or not and please tell me
Is it possible if my application can create paypal account using API from my App?

Comment: Please rephrase your question and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: done kindly now check the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptive Accounts and Adaptive Payments were deprecated years ago, and cannot be used.

In a regular PayPal Checkout flow, an account can always be created when making a payment, so it's unclear why your app needs something additional for this.

The closest thing to something for account creation would be [seller onboarding](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/) with the partner referrals API. You must be an approved partner to use that integration.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it is deprecated really it was headache i contacted the support for permission after that i will check it